# SQLAlchemy with count, group_by and order_by using the ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got several function where I need to do a one-to-many join, using count(), group_by, and order_by.  I'm using the sqlalchemy.select function to produce a query that will return me a set of id's, which I then iterate over to do an ORM select on the individual records.  What I'm wondering is if there is a way to do what I need using the ORM in a single query so that I can avoid having to do the iteration.

Here's an example of what I'm doing now.  In this case the entities are Location and Guide, mapped one-to-many.  I'm trying get a list of the top locations sorted by how many guides they are related to.

```
def popular_world_cities(self):
    query = select([locations.c.id, func.count(Guide.location_id).label('count')],
                   from_obj=[locations, guides],
                   whereclause="guides.location_id = locations.id AND (locations.type = 'city' OR locations.type = 'custom')",
                   group_by=[Location.id],
                   order_by='count desc',
                   limit=10)
    return map(lambda x: meta.Session.query(Location).filter_by(id=x[0]).first(), meta.engine.execute(query).fetchall())
```

**Solution**

I've found the best way to do this.  Simply supply a `from_statement` instead of a `filter_by` or some such. Like so:

```
meta.Session.query(Location).from_statement(query).all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the best way to do this.  Simply supply a `from_statement` instead of a `filter_by` or some such. Like so:

```
meta.Session.query(Location).from_statement(query).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do maps directly to a SQLAlchemy join between a subquery [made from your current select call] and a table. You'll want to move the ordering out of the subselect and create a separate, labeled column with count(desc); order the outer select by that column.

Other than that, I don't see much that's nonobvious.

Answer (score 1):

I found this the hard way but SQLAlchemy does support `group_by`. The documentation under Query doesn't say so but it does support it - I have used it!

And, you can also use `order_by`. I was going to create a special class/query like you did but then I found out there is a `group_by()` function.

Comment: And example might be useful here

Comment: For example (taken from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4086229/890739))
`session.query(Table.column, func.count(Table.column)).group_by(Table.column).all()`