# Group by & count function in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, group-by, count, sqlalchemy

I want a "group by and count" command in sqlalchemy. How can I do this?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370174/sqlalchemy-with-count-groupby-and-orderby-using-the-orm

Answer (score 257, accepted):

The [documentation on counting](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html#counting) says that for `group_by` queries it is better to use `func.count()`:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
session.query(Table.column, 
   func.count(Table.column)).group_by(Table.column).all()
```

Comment: and here's the full statement for those using `Table.query` property instead of `session.query()`:
`Table.query.with_entities(Table.column, func.count(Table.column)).group_by(Table.column).all()`

Comment: @jkukul This should be an answer on its own - I always wondered how to get around this limitation when doing subqueries and wanted to use group_by and count..!

Comment: The edits to this answer render the first sentence kind of meaningless. "Better" than *what*?

Answer (score 66):

If you are using `Table.query` property:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
Table.query.with_entities(Table.column, func.count(Table.column)).group_by(Table.column).all()
```

If you are using `session.query()` method (as stated in miniwark's answer):

```
from sqlalchemy import func
session.query(Table.column, func.count(Table.column)).group_by(Table.column).all()
```

Comment: fantastic. Question. how can i do this? `count(column_name) as total_count`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9187589/7246111

Answer (score 37):

You can also count on multiple groups and their intersection:

```
self.session.query(func.count(Table.column1),Table.column1, Table.column2).group_by(Table.column1, Table.column2).all()
```

The query above will return counts for all possible combinations of values from both columns.

Comment: Thanks for the question, while thinking about it I found an answer to a related question of mine. ;-)