# Using alias() for 'select as' in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

Let's say I have a table 'shares' with the following columns:

```
company    price    quantity
Microsoft  100      10
Google     99       5
Google     99       20
Google     101      15
```

I'd like to run the equivalent of a SQL statement like this:

```sql
select price, 
       sum(quantity) as num 
from shares 
where company='Google' 
group by price;
```

The closest I've come is:

```py
result = (dbsession.query(Shares.price, func.sum(Shares.quantity))
         .filter(Shares.company == 'Google')
         .group_by(Shares.price)
         .all())
```

I'm having trouble with setting up the 'sum(quantity) as num' in sqlalchemy. It appears I need to use alias() but I can't figure out how by looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You actually want the [`label`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html?highlight=label#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.label) method.

```py
result = dbsession.query(
    Shares.price,
    func.sum(Shares.quantity).label("Total sold")
) \
.filter(Shares.company== 'Google') \
.group_by(Shares.price).all()
```

Comment: @user1193814 - **Excellent**, glad I could help!  Welcome to Stackoverflow by the by!  (If the answer helped you, click the green checkbox to let others know it worked.)

Comment: can we use `.label` on column names as well? Like `query(Shares.type.label("shares_type")).group_by(shares_type)`?

Comment: Yes you can, but simply using a label doesn't make it available as a variable in Python so you'll need to group by the field: `query(Shares.type.label("shares_type")).group_by(Shares.type)`

Comment: @Sangram Yes, just put it in quotes. `.group_by("shares_type")`. Discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15557759/1749551).

Comment: hi i have question , how i  to code this sql for sqlalchemy? ```sql
select jsonb_array_elements(subcellular_location) as ttt FROM protein GROUP BY ttt```

Comment: @夏溪辰 - best to ask a separate question for that.

Comment: How do I do the same for booleans: select(obj1.col1 > 50)