# python sqlalchemy label usage

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alias

I know I can use the label method for alias, but I can't figure out how to use the labeled element later in the query - something like the following:

```
session.query(Foo.bar.label("foobar")).filter(foobar > 10).all()
```

Of course, this doesn't work since there is no variable called foobar. How could this be accomplished?

(The over simplified example was just for easy comprehension...)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Offhand, I believe you can use the labeled column itself as an expression:

```
foobar = Foo.bar.label("foobar")
session.query(foobar).filter(foobar > 10).all()
```

Answer (score 32):

Just put foobar in quotes. It'll work for `order_by` like this:

```
session.query(Foo.bar.label("foobar")).order_by('foobar').all()
```

For filter you can use raw sql conditions:

```
session.query(Foo.bar.label("foobar")).filter("foobar > 10").all()
```

Comment: How about putting filter conditions into raw sql? I've updated the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Although this might work (I haven't tried it), my predicate includes dates and those doesn't work well with strings in some DBs

Comment: This worked for me when using `func.sum` whereas @Eevee's answer didn't.

Comment: Any idea how to change the sort order based on a labelled field? I get an error when trying `query = query.order_by("changepct".asc())`

Comment: @raven you can use like this  'order_by(desc("quantity"))'

Answer (score 2):

```
# When you use the SQLAlchemy Core interface you may apply text()
from sqlalchemy import text
stmt = select(Foo.c.bar.label("foobar"))
stmt = stmt.where(text("foobar > 10"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add on to @Eevee's answer:

This can also work similarly for func.coalesce() calls. You can assign the result of `func.coalesce()` to a variable, then reference that variable in a filter. For example:

```py
x = func.coalesce(Order.x, Order.y)
y = query(<model>).filter(x = 10)
```