# SQLAlchemy select from subquery and order by subquery field

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a database table with tweets in a jsonb field.
I have a query to get the tweets ordered by the most retweeted, this is what it looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (raw->'retweeted_status'->'id_str')
     raw->'retweeted_status' as status,
     raw->'retweeted_status'->'retweet_count' as cnt
   FROM tweet
   WHERE (raw->'retweeted_status') is not null
   ORDER BY raw->'retweeted_status'->'id_str', cnt DESC
) t
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

I'm trying to create this query with sqlalchemy, this is where i got so far:

```
session.query(Tweet.raw['retweeted_status'], 
         Tweet.raw['retweeted_status']['retweet_count'].label('cnt'))\
        .filter(~Tweet.raw.has_key('retweeted_status'))\
        .distinct(Tweet.raw['retweeted_status']['id_str']).order_by(Tweet.raw['retweeted_status']['id_str'].desc()).subquery()
```

But how to go from that to order by cnt?

Answer (score 0):

It may not produce the exact query you have shown but should point you in the right direction: you can use your label `'cnt'` in `order_by`, like: `.order_by('cnt')`.

Moreover you can use your label as an argument for `sqlalchemy.desc` function. Summing up:

```
from sqlalchemy import desc

q = (
    session.query(
        Tweet.raw['retweeted_status'],
        Tweet.raw['retweeted_status']['retweet_count'].label('cnt')
    )
    .filter(~Tweet.raw.has_key('retweeted_status'))
    .distinct(
        Tweet.raw['retweeted_status']['id_str']
    )
    .order_by(desc('cnt'))
).subquery()
```

Additional hint: you can format your query nicely if you put it in parentheses.

You may want to read answers to a general question on [python sqlalchemy label usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555920/python-sqlalchemy-label-usage) too.