# with_entities referring to SQlite column aliased with <label> (self-contained repost)

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This is an edited version of the original question, with a self-contained example.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine, func
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    nickname = Column(String)


engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session.add_all([
     User(name='wendy', fullname='Wendy Williams'),
     User(name='mary', fullname='Mary Contrary'),
     User(name='fred', fullname='Fred Flintstone', nickname='freddy')])

session.commit()

items = session.query(
       User.id, User.name,
       func.coalesce(User.nickname, 'Nicky').label('nickname'))

# Checking that with_entities works on original data set
subset_items = session.query(
       User.id, User.name)\
      .with_entities(User.name, User.nickname)\
      .all()
print(subset_items)

# items will be used elsewhere....
# Wanted: a subset with columns fullname and nickname only
# Result is wrong, it does not use coalesce result
special_items = items\
       .with_entities(User.fullname, User.nickname) \
       .all()
print(special_items)
```

How do I use .with_entities to refer to the items? The following fails

```
.with_entities(items.fullname, items.nickname) \
```

so did variants with quotes as suggested by @Nick in reply to the original question.

Comment: Can you provide the error you're getting? That might give a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: There is no error, but nickname is Null for 1 and 2, instead of "Nicky"

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I believe you should be able to [use a string here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15555920/1749551) instead of an expression:

```
.with_entities('pat_no') \
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there was no reply, I posted this on the community site of [SQLAlchemy](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/jknmMxlsom8). The answer is surprisingly awkward:

`q = q.with_entities(q.column_descriptions[1]['expr'], q.column_descriptions[2]['expr'])`