# Using alias on column in sqlalchemy and use that alias in group_by

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to convert an SQL to sqlalchemy.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct product_code) as prod FROM purchase_detail 
GROUP BY user_id )  tab WHERE tab.prod ='000'
```

With the information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187530/using-alias-for-select-as-in-sqlalchemy) link I tried to come up with this.

```
db_session.query(PurchaseDetail.user_id, 
           func.group_concat(PurchaseDetail.product_code.label("code")).
           group_by(PurchaseDetail.user_id).filter_by(code='000')
```

This obviously throws an error saying purchase_detail doesn't have a column called code. I kind of knew the label would not work here. 
How can I can give an alias to that grouped column and filter on that column?

Comment: The original SQL won't work. The `tab` subquery doesn't return a `produce_code` column, it returns `prod`.

Comment: @Barmar : My bad. Editing question now. Thanks for pointing.