# making alias for case statement in the where clause - SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I need to create a calculated column in my SQL query using SQLAlchemy. 
The query i would like to get will look like this:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN (age < 18) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS kid 
FROM (SELECT TEST_TABLE.index AS index, TEST_TABLE.age AS age, TEST_TABLE.letter AS letter 
FROM TEST_TABLE) AS dataset
```

Now, I managed to do so with SQLAlchemy like this:

```
query = select(['*', case([(Column('age').op('<')(18), 1)], else_=0)])
query.select_from(alias(select([*]), name='dataset'))   # I actually pass different params here, but this is an example
```

But I didn't manage to put another alias() function to make the calculated column that i added be called "kid" like I want. SQLAlchemy generates its own alias for it instead.

I tried:

```
query = select(['*', case([(alias(Column('age').op('<')(18), name='kid'), 1)], else_=0)])
```

and:

```
query = select(['*', alias(case([(Column('age').op('<')(18), 1)], else_=0), name='kid')])
```

No success there. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Case _expression_.

Comment: @jarlh please elaborate

Comment: A case expression returns a value, just like you use it. A case statement is used to do conditional execution of code, for example in stored procedures - and returns no value. expression <> statement

Comment: How does this helps me alias that column?

Comment: I'm not into sqlalchemy but maybe you can use `label()` for the the column: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.label
`alias()` is used in the From Clause e.g. for aliasing a Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comment I'm not familiar with sqlalchemy. But maybe this will help you:

```
query = select(['*', case([(Column('age').op('<')(18), 1)], else_=0).label("kid")])
query.select_from(alias(select([*]), name='dataset'))
```

But I'm really not sure if the syntax is right here. Maybe also look here: [Using alias() for 'select as' in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187530/using-alias-for-select-as-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: That was exactly what i was looking for.