# Aggregate function expression is put in the `FROM` clause

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a query into a model (`Loan`) filtered by some criteria and joined into another model (`LoanPayment`).

The first model has a one-to-many relationship with the second, and I'd like to collect an aggregate value over a column of the second model.

The models are defined like this:

```
class Loan(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'loan'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    granted_date = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    state = Column(String(50), default='GRANTED', index=True)
    value = Column(Numeric(19, 10, asdecimal=True),
                   nullable=False, default=money.Decimal(0))
    [... other columns ...]

class LoanPayout(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'loan_payout'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    payment_date = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    value = Column(Numeric(19, 10, asdecimal=True),
                   nullable=False, default=money.Decimal(0))
    loan_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('loan.id'),
                     nullable=False, index=True)
    loan = relationship('Loan',
                        backref=backref('payouts', lazy='dynamic',),
                        foreign_keys=[loan_id], order_by=payment_date.asc)
    [... other columns ...]
```

I'd like to query all `Loan.granted_date` records, filtering according to a certain criteria (say `state='LATE'`), and also return the `sum()` of values of all related payouts, grouped by loan.

I tried the following orm query:

```
session.query(
    Loan.id,
    Loan.granted_date,
    func.sum(LoanPayout.principal).alias('loan_payout_total'),
).filter(
    Loan.state == 'LATE',
).join(
    LoanPayout
).group_by(Loan.id)
```

But SQLAlchemy (version 1.2.13) is rendering the following, which is not even valid SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    loan.id AS loan_id,
    loan.sale_date AS loan_sale_date,
    loan_payout_total.sum_1 AS loan_payout_total_sum_1
FROM
    sum(loan_payout.principal) AS loan_payout_total,
    loan
JOIN loan_payout
    ON loan.id = loan_payout.loan_id
WHERE
    loan.state = %(state_1)s
GROUP BY
    loan.id
```

The query is almost what I expect: it joins correctly the two tables, renders the `sum()` column correctly and groups by the expected column.

But it puts what should have been the `sum()` column with its alias in the `FROM` section instead of the `SELECT` section:

```
FROM
    sum(loan_payout.principal) AS loan_payout_total,
    loan
```

And then it puts an aliased column supposedly coming from that weird "selectable" into the `SELECT` clause:

```
    loan_payout_total.sum_1 AS loan_payout_total_sum_1
```

How do I get SQLAlchemy to render this query correctly, using the ORM support?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187530/using-alias-for-select-as-in-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
func.sum(LoanPayout.principal).alias('loan_payout_total')
```

you want a [label](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.label):

```
func.sum(LoanPayout.principal).label('loan_payout_total')
```

[`FunctionElement.alias()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.alias) produces an aliased `FROM`-item, which is why it is put in the `FROM` clause. It's valid in for example Postgresql.

Comment: Thank you. I can understand why both `.label()` and `.alias()` are available on `func.xxx()`, but I can't, for the life of me, understand why they wouldn't just make it generate the correct code depending on the context (`FROM` vs `SELECT`)

Comment: It actually has a logic to it that you'll run into using SQLA. Passing selectable things (tables, models, aliases, CTEs) as entities to query building constructs automatically add them to the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Also, personally I'd find it a lot more confusing, if the produced alias construct acted entirely differently in different contexts. Everywhere in SQLA `alias()` is used to produce "table" aliases, while `label()` names column expressions.