# How to convert this SQL query counting months and group by the month to sqlalchemy?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use sqlalchemy with postgresql to get data.

and I'd like to use this query

```
SELECT MONTH(date_field1), COUNT(*)
FROM table1
GROUP BY MONTH(date_field1)
```

so I can get the list of months and its count like below

```
month | count
1 | 3521
2 | 5222
3 | 1122
4 | 559
5 | 1664
6 | 3521
7 | 5222
8 | 1122
9 | 559
10 | 1664
11 | 559
12 | 1664
```

Comment: Please post the SQL-alchemy model of your table. Also please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052148/group-by-count-function-in-sqlalchemy), it's in the same scope as yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqlalchemy has 2 different [mode](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/): `ORM` and `core`

Assuming I have a table with a 'created' column being a date, you can achieve what you want with the following:

- Using the `ORM` mode:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

qry = session.query(func.month(Table.created), func.count(Table.created)).group_by(Table.created)
```

- With `core`:

```
from sqlalchemy import select 
from sqlalchemy import func

qry = select([func.month(tbl.c.created), func.count(tbl.c.created)]).group_by(tbl.c.created)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what i wanted to know about sqlalchemy.