# flask sqlalchemy one-to-many filter, count & grouping

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am currently trying to build a query which
give me for a one-to-many sqlalchemy query in flask both my result filters grouped and then says how many individual entries there are for it

Following is my database model to illustrate the question:

```
class cellphone(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'cellphone'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    number = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True)
    sms = db.relationship('sms_accounting',  backref="cellphone", lazy='dynamic')
    

class sms_accounting(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'sms_accounting'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    cellphone_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cellphone.id'))
```

**What I want to do now is find out how many SMS were sent within X days per number.**

Filtering and grouping I managed to do, but to calculate the sum per device correctly is not possible.

```
def sms_count():
    search_peroid='90' #time to fetch events in days
    period_start = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=int(search_peroid))
    phone_count = sms_accounting.query.filter(sms_accounting.timestamp.between(period_start, \
        datetime.utcnow() )).group_by(sms_accounting.cellphone_id).all()
```

I found some examples for func.count, but unfortunately none of them works. This already starts with the usage,

`AttributeError: BaseQuery object has no attribute 'func'`

even though it was imported especially.

`from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import func`

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I am wrong.

As an option, you could try executing an SQL Query through Flask.

`db.session.execute('select number, count(sms_accounting.id) from cellphone join sms_accounting on sms_accounting.cellphone_id = cellphone.id');`

You can easily add the time based filter using `where`.

Regarding the *AttributeError*, are you sure you are using the 'func' method properly? The correct usage can be found on this unrelated answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4086229/4854064. It might be that you accidentally called `func` as a method of the `query` object.