# for loop output scope

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am new to Python flask and would like to put the results of a loop in a variable but is seems out of scope.

How can i get this to the parent scope, the view scope, in snippet below?

```
@users.route('/list', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
    users = User.query.all()
    link_count = {}
    for user in users:
        link_count = Link.query.filter(Link.user_id == user.id).count()
        flash(f'{link_count}') # works and gives me a list/ array
    flash(f'{link_count}') # null
    return render_template('user_stats.html', title='Users', users=users)
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: Do you need to get total count of links?

Comment: Can you explain your goal for the link_count variable? Are you trying to get a total per user? And then reference it based on the user's id? Or what?
Or do you want a total count for all users put together?

Answer (score 2):

Use this and then reference your link_count variable in jinja in your template

```
@users.route('/list', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
    users = User.query.all()
    link_count = {}
    for user in users:
        link_count = Link.query.filter(Link.user_id == user.id).count()
        flash(f'{link_count}') # works and gives me a list/ array
    flash(f'{link_count}') # null
    return render_template('user_stats.html', title='Users', users=users, link_count=link_count )
```

Any data you're using on the template side you have to send as a parameter in the render_template method

### edit1:

I'm not sure why you're using a dictionary for link_count.
To justify using a dictionary you should be doing something like this inside your for loop

```
link_count[user.id] = Link.query.filter(Link.user_id == user.id).count()
```

And then in your jinja template, you can reference a data point like this

```
{{ link_count[1] }}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you? @odin

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad way to do it with a loop. You will make an SQL request to db for every user. All you need is just to make a group by function through SQLAlchemy.
You can find an example here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4086229/14690802