# SQLmodel and group_by

Tags: mysql, group-by, fastapi, sqlmodel

I recently completed the SQLmodel documentation, but it doesn't tell me how to use the group_by command.
I am trying the following:

```sql
SELECT reader_status, count(book_id) 
FROM readerbook
WHERE reader_id=1
GROUP BY reader_id, reader_status
```

to be used in the SQLmodel code.

```
statement = select(
    ReaderBook.reader_status, func.count(ReaderBook.book_id).label("count")
)
```

This is my code. How do I use the group_by "reader_id" condition ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by & count function in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052148/group-by-count-function-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: Thank you! I tried using this but the group_by doesn't work.
I imported the func from sqlalchemy, everything else seems to work except for group_by
Do I have to import something else ?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `readerBook` is the variable of the table i.e.

```
readerBook = Table(
   ...
)
```

Then you can try the following.

```
statement = select([
    readerBook.c.reader_status, func.count(readerBook.c.book_id).label("count")
])
.select_from(readerBook)
.group_by(readerBook.c.reader_id)
```